# permutations of String

Tags: java

I am trying to write a simple method that prints all String permutations. There are a lot of topics on permutations of a given string, but that is not what I seek.
I want to start with strings from 1 letter and go on to Strings of 10 letters.

In the end I found that it is fairly easy to do this for hex code:

```
int counter = 0;
while (true) {      
    String a = Integer.toString(counter, 16); //fails on 26
    System.out.println(a);
    counter++;
}
```

But if I change the radix 16 to 26, nothing happens(all 0's are printed). It would surprise me if it would work actually : ), cause i did not check the docs for the radix that are allowed.
Still I would like to keep the same method and just treat my String as a large number with radix 26.

How do I convert the number to a radix 26 String?

Comment: Ok, never mind, suddenly it is working... Maximum Radix =36

Comment: Assuming it takes only 1 nanosecond to create and print a string of 10 characters (and it probably takes much more than that), just to print all the Strings composed of 10 characters going from 'a' to 'z' will take 26^10 nanoseconds, or more than 39 hours. Do you really want to do that?

Comment: I will probably not get to 10 characters, but it will be code that can run for weeks, no problem. It is background analysis.